# Brazilian Currency Remove mask Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Guys i have this mask that uses(jQuery MaskMoney plugin)

For example, if i type R$5.000,00 in the input and apply my function with this RegEx, it returns 5000.00, i want a Regex that returns 5000,00

`$("#whatever").maskMoney({
            prefix: "R$",
            decimal: ",",
            thousands: "."
        }); 
function RemoveMask(value) {
    var result = parseFloat(value.replace(/,/g, '.').replace(/[.](?=.*[.])/g, '').replace(/\R\$/g, '').replace(' ', ''));
    return result;
} 
RemoveMask($("#whatever").val())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```js
function RemoveMask(value) {
  value = value.replace(/\./g, "");
  return /\d+,\d+/.exec(value)[0].toString();
}

console.log(RemoveMask("R$5.000,00"));
console.log(RemoveMask("R$5.000,02"));
console.log(RemoveMask("Lorem Ipsum R$5.000,05 test"));
console.log(RemoveMask("Lorem Ipsum R$5.000,00 test"));
console.log(RemoveMask("Lorem Ipsum R$500,00 test"));
console.log(RemoveMask("Lorem Ipsum R$0,05 test"));
console.log(RemoveMask("Lorem Ipsum R$0,50 test"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`slice` off the currency symbols then `replace` the others:

```js
const str = "R$5.000,00";
const res = str.slice(2).replace(/\./g, "").replace(/,/g, ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a npm library that supports multiple currencies, so you don't need to worry about regex:

```js
import currencyToFloat from 'currency-to-float';

const price = 'R$ 1,99';

const parsed = currencyToFloat(price);

console.log(parsed); // 1.99
```